# Continuous input to choose while loop in Python

Tags: python, loops, io, raspberry-pi, distance

I'm on Raspberry Pi, using Python.
I would like to receive continuous input from a distance sensor and have the distance value determine whether or not to send output.

I have a output function, gogo, and a sense function, sense, which updates the distance value.

I'd like to have the output start when below 20 distance and the output stop when the distance reaches threshold of 20, but the only solution that I can see is another loop.

My code is not working and I'm thinking that there's a nice solution, but I am not well-versed in loops.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

distance = 40.0

TRIG = 4
ECHO = 18

GPIO.setup(TRIG,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(ECHO,GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.OUT)

def gogo(): 
    Motor1A = 23
    Motor1B = 24
    Motor1E = 25

    GPIO.setup(Motor1A,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(Motor1B,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(Motor1E,GPIO.OUT)

    print "Turning motor on"
    GPIO.output(Motor1A,GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(Motor1B,GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(Motor1E,GPIO.HIGH)

def sense():
    GPIO.output(TRIG, True)
    time.sleep(0.00001)
    GPIO.output(TRIG, False)

    while GPIO.input(ECHO) == False:
        start = time.time()

    while GPIO.input(ECHO) == True:
        end = time.time()

    sig_time = end-start

#CM:
    distance = sig_time / 0.000058

#inches:
#distance = sig_time / 0.000148

    print('Distance: {} centimeters'.format(distance))

while distance > 20.0:
    print (distance)
    sense()
else:
    print (distance)
    gogo()
    sense()

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is scope; `distance` is constantly in your 40 main code.  It gets updated only in `sense()`

First, let's edit sense to return the value of distance

```
def sense():
    GPIO.output(TRIG, True)
    time.sleep(0.00001)
    GPIO.output(TRIG, False)

    while GPIO.input(ECHO) == False:
        start = time.time()

    while GPIO.input(ECHO) == True:
        end = time.time()

    sig_time = end-start

#CM:
    distance = sig_time / 0.000058

#inches:
#distance = sig_time / 0.000148

    print('Distance: {} centimeters'.format(distance))
    return distance
```

you should also probably create a function that turns the motor off

you need to define distance, also let's make a loop that runs forever.  right now, your loop only runs until distance< 20

```
distance = sense()
while True:
    if distance > 20:
        <call motor off function here>
        print (distance)
    else:
        print (distance)
        gogo()
    distance = sense() #now we're checking distance every cycle
```

Comment: Awesome!  I'll try this when I get home.  Thank you Mohommad

Comment: @peer if this worked for you, please accept it as an answer so others know to try it

Comment: This is actually what I went with.  var = 1
while var == 1:
 sense()
 time.sleep(0.01)
 if distance < 20.0:
  gogo()
 else:
  stosto()